# Mesos slave container with Oracle Linux 7 base image fails to start

Tags: linux, docker, mesos, mesosphere

I created a mesos slave docker image with Oracle Linux 7.2 as the base image. The dockerfile builds correctly but when I try to run the image, it gives the following error:

```
I0414 17:57:30.659329     1 logging.cpp:188] INFO level logging started!
I0414 17:57:30.666347     1 main.cpp:223] Build: 2016-03-17 17:47:25 by root
I0414 17:57:30.666445     1 main.cpp:225] Version: 0.28.0
I0414 17:57:30.666483     1 main.cpp:228] Git tag: 0.28.0
I0414 17:57:30.666543     1 main.cpp:232] Git SHA: 961edbd82e691a619a4c171a7aadc9c32957fa73
I0414 17:57:30.726467     1 systemd.cpp:236] systemd version `219` detected
I0414 17:57:30.726622     1 main.cpp:240] Inializing systemd state
Failed to initialize systemd: Failed to locate systemd runtime directory: /run/systemd/system
```

Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM oraclelinux:7.2

RUN rpm -Uvh http://repos.mesosphere.io/el/7/noarch/RPMS/mesosphere-el-repo-7-1.noarch.rpm
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install mesos

ENTRYPOINT ["mesos-slave"]
```

The OS of the host machine is Oracle Linux 7.2 as well. I was able to run an image build with Ubuntu 14.04 as well as the existing image created by Mesosphere (https://hub.docker.com/r/mesosphere/mesos-slave/) successfully.

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10):

Try this in your Dockerfile:

```
ENV MESOS_SYSTEMD_ENABLE_SUPPORT false
```

Answer (score -3):

docker can't start systemd in runtime. this is core reason.